# HDD mounts then immediately unmounts

Tags: external-hdd, automount

My wife had received a virus on her iMac some time ago. When updating to the new OSX, the update had a critical failure. Several attempts to recover the drive through the Mac failed. I decided to take this to Ubuntu as I've had some success; however, I immediately noticed odd things.

1) The HDD will mount on fdisk, but will not show up in the file explorer
2) Terminal would not allow me to navigate to the folder

I stepped away for a week to allow my head to clear, but now the HDD (now in USB enclosure) will mount for approximately 5 seconds then discounts. I ran `dmesg` and received the following read out:

```
Dec 16 20:19:03 HAL wpa_supplicant[1501]: message repeated 29 times: [ wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED ]
Dec 16 20:20:23 HAL wpa_supplicant[1501]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 00:26:50:38:88:19 [GTK=TKIP]
Dec 16 20:21:03 HAL wpa_supplicant[1501]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Dec 16 20:21:31 HAL wpa_supplicant[1501]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying compl>eted with 00:26:50:38:88:19 [GTK=TKIP]
Dec 16 20:23:03 HAL wpa_supplicant[1501]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Dec 16 20:41:03 HAL wpa_supplicant[1501]: message repeated 9 times: [ wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED ]
Dec 16 20:41:27 HAL wpa_supplicant[1501]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 00:26:50:38:88:19 [GTK=TKIP]
Dec 16 20:41:58 HAL compiz: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid error
Dec 16 20:43:03 HAL wpa_supplicant[1501]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Dec 16 20:43:26 HAL sudo: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/daniel is already mounted
Dec 16 20:48:08 HAL kernel: [12197.352065] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 15 using ehci-pci
Dec 16 20:48:09 HAL kernel: [12197.484984] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=4971, idProduct=8017
Dec 16 20:48:09 HAL kernel: [12197.484990] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=11, SerialNumber=3
Dec 16 20:48:09 HAL kernel: [12197.484993] usb 1-1: Product: G-RAID
Dec 16 20:48:09 HAL kernel: [12197.484996] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
Dec 16 20:48:09 HAL kernel: [12197.484999] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 20120912000A
Dec 16 20:48:09 HAL kernel: [12197.485774] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Dec 16 20:48:09 HAL kernel: [12197.488420] scsi18 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0
Dec 16 20:48:09 HAL mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 15: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.1/usb1/1-1"
Dec 16 20:48:09 HAL mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 15 was not an MTP device
Dec 16 20:48:10 HAL kernel: [12198.672764] scsi 18:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HGST                           PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
Dec 16 20:48:10 HAL kernel: [12198.673119] sd 18:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Dec 16 20:48:10 HAL kernel: [12199.086000] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
Dec 16 20:48:10 HAL kernel: [12199.271016] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] 5860533168 512-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
Dec 16 20:48:10 HAL kernel: [12199.273757] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Dec 16 20:48:10 HAL kernel: [12199.273762] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 34 00 00 00
Dec 16 20:48:10 HAL kernel: [12199.275744] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Dec 16 20:48:10 HAL kernel: [12199.460387] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
Dec 16 20:48:11 HAL kernel: [12199.712521]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3
Dec 16 20:48:11 HAL kernel: [12199.897384] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
Dec 16 20:48:11 HAL kernel: [12200.273749] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Dec 16 20:48:15 HAL kernel: [12204.259079] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 15
```

After this, the drive does not show up on `fdisk -l` 
I cannot think of any way to keep the drive mounted and it does not stay mounted long enough to run anything on it. I'm trying to recover the photos from the drive. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance! If you need any more info, please let me know.

I should also state that I have used another HDD on this same enclosure and it works just fine. The problem lies somewhere with the HDD.

Comment: Not sure if it is going anywhere, but can you see the disk (and maybe mount) with Gparted (or get more information)?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and which kernel are you using?

Comment: It does not show up on GParted. I am running Ubuntu 14.10 3.16.0-28-generic